# Take screenshot of image using html2canvas display nothing in downloaded image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html2canvas

While taking a screenshot of the external image through html2canvas will display nothing in the downloaded image.

When I use my local image then it will download perfectly.

`My` [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tctz79ho/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get solution?